# How to put a constraint on the dual variable of the another constraint in Pyomo?

Tags: constraints, pyomo, suffix

I am working on an economic model and I need to put a cap on the dual of one of the constraints but I have errors. I would be thankful if someone could help.
At the beginning of the code, I put this line:

`model.dual = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.IMPORT_EXPORT)` 
Here is the constraint I have defined on the dual:

`model.adequacy_constraint = \ pyo.Constraint(model.h, rule=adequacy_constraint_rule) def lost_load_rule(model, h):\ return model.dual[model.adequacy_constraint[h]]< 1e9 model.voll_constraint = \ pyo.Constraint(model.h, rule=lost_load_rule)`

here is the error:

`return model.dual[model.adequacy_constraint[h]]< 1e9 File "C:\Users\Maryam\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyomo\common\collections\component_map.py", line 96, in __getitem__ raise KeyError("Component with id '%s': %s" KeyError: "Component with id '2384738399616': adequacy_constraint[0]"`

Answer (score 0):

You can't put restrictions on the duals in traditional optimization models. If you really need to, and dualizing the model is not an option, you may want to look into Complementarity and MPEC models.